# Were can I find "flutter pub list" or "flutter pub search" command line tools?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Where can I find a command line tool for searching and listing installed packaged versions and available upgrade versions?

I can't think of any other package management tool that doesn't include commands to list installed versions or find available upgrades without actually upgrading.

For example, if my pubspec.yaml restricts a version, there is no easy way to check which of my pinned packages could be upgraded if I lift the restriction. Similarly, it might be possible to see what versions of a particular package may be available at the command line.

I'd prefer to use a command line tool because it is a vastly faster workflow than needing to check a website for every package you might be using or have inherited via a dependency.

Comment: I also hope to find search, but there is not search command at all. Maybe we should search from the website.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `flutter pub deps` command to list all package information including their versions.

Comment: But this doesn't actually show all the versions - it looks like it only shows direct dependency versions, but not the version of the things those dependencies rely on

Answer (score 1):

On May 6, the command `flutter pub outdated` has been introduced with the release of Dart 2.8. It shows the current and upgradable versions of the packages imported.

If it doesn't work, update your Flutter version with `flutter upgrade`.

Comment: It only seems to show things that could be upgraded. And it doesn't work if you have a problem that listing dependencies might help with: 
`The pubspec.yaml file has changed since the pubspec.lock file was generated, please run "pub get" again.`

Comment: Isn't that what you asked ? And I didn't understand the 2nd part of your comment, but if the lockfile is blocking you, delete it or run `pub upgrade`.

Comment: `outdated` only seems to report on specific packages that can be upgraded. And it only works if you can successfully run `pub get` which I couldn't because something got upgraded that created a conflict in dependancies. If I could have simply listed all available versions of packages I had installed, I could have easily figured out the problem instead of needing to search the web to find down-grade version numbers.

Comment: This part is the part you missed. "listing installed packaged versions" -- sorry that I wasn't clearer in my question.

Answer (score 1):

The Dart package manager is a very limited in functionality software product (this is a well-known fact).
For this reason, you may not find the functionality that you expect from such software.

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
flutter pub upgrade -n
```

`flutter pub upgrade` will list all packages and upgrade them. The `-n` makes it so it only lists them without upgrading